# How to add specific CSS attributes to all text-containing elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

Say I have a standard stackoverflow question page and I want to append an attribute such as "font-family: monospace" to every text-containing element by using a Google Chrome extension.

Is this possible using javascript? If I understand correctly, even using getElementsByTagName() on every element tag would get overridden if the elements had class names that were given different values in the page's CSS.

Comment: What is an "text-containing" element? Ultimately, tags like `<html>` and `<body>` are "text-containing", because they... ... contain text. Are you actually asking how to make sure that the style that you apply via your extension takes precedence over the styles of the web page itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append a style to your `<head>` element, targeting all elements (seeing as font family would only apply to text elements anyway).

So, in your javascript, you would append the head section with:

```
<style>
  *{
  font-family:monospace;
  }
</style>
```

*Note, for security reasons, SO snippets are contained and so a 'proper' live demo is out of the question here.*

**Demo snippet**

```js
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('*').css("font-family","monospace");
    });
```

```css
div{
  font-family:"Arial";
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head></head>

<body>
hi. I'm text
  <button id="btn">change</button>
  <div>
    I've been given a font family already
    </div>
</body>
```

If you wanted to *force* this (that is, if the site has used the `!important` tag in *their* declaration of font-family site ), you **may** then have to add the dreaded `!important` tag, since this would be overridden if this had been used (pretty much) anywhere in the site's css.

This would be achieved using the setProperty method:

```
 this.style.setProperty( 'height', '0px', 'important' );
});
```

is just an example of it use.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can iterate through every element and add style.
Hierarchy is following:

- .class
- inline style
- .class with `!important`

  example: `.test-class {font-family:monospace !important }`
- inline style with `!important`

---

You can read more [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/web-designer/css-specificity-hierarchy-what-you-need-to-know/)